# Write to console when span element disappears

Tags: javascript

Please consider my below script. What it is intended to do is:

- script runs in the browser console
- script is checking a website every second whether a certain `span` exists or not
- as soon as the `span` appears, output to the console "span exists"
- keep checking every second. For as long as the span is there, do nothing. As soon as the `span` disappears (website is dynamic), output to console "span disappeared"

The `span` can have multiple values ("buy", "sell", etc.) which is why there is an if-statement to check whether the `span` content is "buy", since I am for now only interested in this case.

The issue is:

- as soon as the `span` appears, I get the expected output to console:

  span appeared
- but as soon as the span disappears, the console output falls in an infinite loop:

  span disappeared
  span appeared
  span disappeared
  span appeared
  span disappeared

This should not be. The script should write `span disappeared` once and then wait for the span to appear again, at which point it should write to the console `span appeared` again.

```
function f() {
    try {
        b = document.querySelector('#main > header > div>div>span').textContent;
    } 
    catch (TypeError) { // element does not exit
        if (span_exists) {
            // if it does not exist, but it did previously, then it just disappeared
            console.log("span disappeared" + "\n");
            span_exists = false;
        }
        return;
    }

    if (b === "buy") { // element exists
        if (span_exists) {
            // span existed already.. do nothing
        }
        else { // span just appeared
            console.log("span appeared" + "\n");
            span_exists = true;
        }
    }
}


function check_span() {
    span_exists = false;
    interval = setInterval(f, 1000);
    alert("checking for span");
    return interval;
}

> check_span()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you never clear the interval?

Comment: Where would I do that? Also, I don't think this is where the issue is, because it seems to be in the `span_exists` value?